# Print region of US country in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am new in magento development.
    I try to access all US state  and then compare all with one i.e. 'Arizona' if condition is true then it pass its abbreviation to my phtml file.

my phpfunction is:-

```
public function getAbbr(){
$collection = Mage::getModel('directory/region_api' )->items('US'); 
        foreach($collection as $region){
      if($region=='Arizona)
       echo 'AZ';
          }
}
```

My jascript code is:-

```
var abbr=<?php echo $this->getAbbr()?>
```

But it not works.
    please any one magento expert give me proper step by step suggestion how i achieve that?

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an exception? Please update your question.

Answer (score 0):

try this, you have missed single quotation mark in 4th line

`public function getAbbr(){
    $collection = Mage::getModel('directory/region_api' )->items('US'); 
    foreach($collection as $region){
        if($region=='Arizona')
           echo 'AZ';
        }
}`